# Generating, compiling and using Java code at run time?

Tags: java, compilation

I have a scenario where I have to generate Java code when my application is running.

Can compile and run than code from my application( as a separate application).

Is it possible to compile and then use it from the same application. Cant think of any possibility

Answer (score 11):

Check out [Create dynamic applications with javax.tools](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jcomp/). *Second time I've referenced this today--I swear I don't work for them.*

Comment: The link in this answer is broken now.

Comment: That's too bad, maybe this [other Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13697582/use-of-javax-tools-to-compile-java-source-at-runtime) will be useful.

Answer (score 5):

You can use an instance of [JavaCompiler](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/tools/JavaCompiler.html):

```
JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
```

Follow the link for the an example on how to use it.

Comment: Note that you will need a JDK for this to work.  The JRE install does not include a compiler.

Comment: Good point Thorbjørn. If he chooses this alternative, the minimum requirement for his application will be **JDK 6**.

Comment: JRE 7 appears to have put javax.tools.ToolProvider right in the rt.jar. Although I haven't tested this out, I do see in `jdk1.7.0_05/jre/lib/rt.jar`:
`javax/tools/JavaCompiler.class` and `javax/tools/ToolProvider.class`

Answer (score 1):

using the [ProcessBuilder](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/index.html?java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) or [Runtime.exec()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/index.html?java/lang/Runtime.html) you can run any commandline app from your java code

this includes the javac compiler and java as a separate process

Comment: When running MyCompilingUtility.java, which calls`Runtime#exec()` with a parameter of `javac MyFile.java` where `MyFile.java` was created via `PrintWriter` by `MyCompilingUtility.java`, I don't see a `class` file generated for `MyFile.java`. Why's that?

Comment: check the error output of javac, javac expects the working directory to be the root package of the class it is compiling

Comment: Thanks, @ratchet freak. Posting Sotirios Delimanolis's comment to elaborate on your helpful suggestion - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21580975/using-runtimeexec-with-javac-no-class-file/21581168?noredirect=1#comment32600305_21581168