# Compile Java classes at runtime of Eclipse Plugin

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, compilation, java-compiler-api, runtime-compilation

I'm in a very awkward situation here.
Im developping an 'Eclipse plugin' that has to 'compile' .java files into .class files (or maybe even a jar).

I am trying to use the [Java Compiler API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/tools/JavaCompiler.html) in order to do something like this :

```
public class Compiler {
    private  JavaCompiler _javaCompiler;
    private  StandardJavaFileManager _sjfm = null;
    private   Files[] _filesIn;
    
    public Compiler()
    {
        _javaCompiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
        _sjfm =  _javaCompiler.getStandardFileManager(null, null, null);
    }
    
    public  void CompileFiles(ArrayList<String> strings, String outputFolder)
    {
        //_javaCompiler.run
        Iterable fileObject = _sjfm.getJavaFileObjectsFromStrings(strings);
        String[] options = new String[]{"-d", outputFolder};
        _javaCompiler.getTask(null, null, null, Arrays.asList(options), null, fileObject).call();
        try {
            _sjfm.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
    }
}
```

The problem is, when I call `_sjfm =  _javaCompiler.getStandardFileManager(null, null, null);` I run into a NullPointerException because, this is an 'expected' behavior when not running the JDK (please refer to this [bug report](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6477844))

This [StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13697582/use-of-javax-tools-to-compile-java-souce-at-runtime) helped me in some way, but what would be the correct way to compile Java files from within an Eclipse Plugin that must be publishable ?

1. Use an alternative "compiler" and just include the jars and use them ?
2. Include tools.jar (that is found in the JDK folder) in my plugin, dynamically load it, and compile from it ?
3. Any other solution that I cant think of

What would you recommend ?

Comment: You can try to use the Eclipse JDT compiler: http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Fjdt_api_compile.htm

Comment: yeah, im gonna go with this idea. I knew eclipse had its own compiler, but never thought of using it. Post an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Eclipse JDT compiler, as described at http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Fjdt_api_compile.htm.