# Using Runtime#exec() with javac - No Class File

Tags: java, runtime

The following `MyCompilingUtility.java` creates a file (a Java class - `AutoGenerated.java`) via a `PrintWriter`. This class only has a Main method with a print statement.  Secondly, this program calls `javac AutoGenerated.java`.

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException, 
   FileNotFoundException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
    createFile("AutoGenerated.java");
    compile("AutoGenerated.java");
}

public static void compile(String fileName) throws IOException {
    final String javacPath = "C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_51/bin/javac.exe";
    Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
    final String compileCmd = javacPath + " " + fileName;
    rt.exec(compileCmd);
}

public static void createFile(String fileName) throws FileNotFoundException,
       UnsupportedEncodingException  {
    PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(fileName, "UTF-8");
    writer.println("public class AutoGenerated");
    writer.println("{");
    writer.println("  public static void main(String [] args)");
    writer.println("  {");
    writer.println("    System.out.println(\"Hello from AutoGenerated World\")");
    writer.println("  }");
    writer.println("}");
    writer.close();
}
```

However, after running `javac MyCompilingUtility.java && java MyCompilingUtility`, there's no `AutoGenerated.class` file produced.

Why is that?

Comment: Get the `Process` from `exec()` and call its `waitFor` method. What code did it return?

Comment: I should've read the docs. @SotiriosDelimanolis. Running `waitFor` returns 1. These docs(http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#waitFor()) say `0` indicates normal completion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a `;` at the end of

```
writer.println("    System.out.println(\"Hello from AutoGenerated World\");");
                                                                          ^
```

The compiler simply fails to compile it.

Comment: @KevinMeredith For future reference, steps to reproduce: ran your code, modified it to add check for the exit code, read the error `InputStream` (`Process#getErrorStream()`) and it said exactly the problem.